# Python || Download dataset from kaggle and upload to Amazon S3 bucket without local storage in between

Tags: python, amazon-s3, dataset, boto3, kaggle

below script downloads a dataset from Kaggle, saves it on my local computer and uploads it to Amazon S3. Since I would like to host my script online and schedule a daily run I need to avoid storing the dataset on my local computer. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError
import datetime
import io
import os
import pandas as pd
import zipfile
from kaggle.api.kaggle_api_extended import KaggleApi
import kaggle

# set your kaggle username
os.environ['KAGGLE_USERNAME'] = 'kaggleusername' # please replace with your kaggle username 

# set your kaggle token
os.environ['KAGGLE_KEY'] = 'kagglekey' # please replace with your kaggle api key 

# connect to kaggle
api = KaggleApi()
api.authenticate()

# set your download directory
local_path = 'C:\\Users\\Myuser\\Documents\\datasets'

# get date
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d%m%y')

# Download the dataset to above defined path
kaggle.api.dataset_download_files('davidcariboo/player-scores', path = local_path, unzip = True)

# Connection to AWS S3
s3 = boto3.resource(
    service_name='s3',
    region_name='eu-central-1',
    aws_access_key_id='myaccesskeyid',
    aws_secret_access_key='mysecretaccesskey'
)

# Upload files to S3 bucket
def fetch_files_and_upload(local_path, bucket_name, bucket_folder):
    for file_name in os.listdir(local_path):
        if file_name.endswith('.csv'):
            s3_file = bucket_folder + '/' + file_name
            s3.Bucket(bucket_name).upload_file(local_path +'/'+ file_name, s3_file)
            print(f'Uploaded {file_name} to S3')
            
# Renaming of files
def rename_files_in_dir(local_path):
    for filename in os.listdir(local_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(local_path, filename)): 
            base_file, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
            new_file = base_file + '_' + date + ext  
            os.rename(os.path.join(local_path, filename), os.path.join(local_path, new_file))
            print(f'File renamed from {filename} to {new_file}')
            
 fetch_files_and_upload(local_path, 'my-bucket', 'active')

rename_files_in_dir(local_path)

fetch_files_and_upload(local_path, 'my-bucket', 'archive/' + date)
```

Comment: You can achieve this using io.StringIO().